# Post middleware doesn`t work on findOneAndUpdate event

Tags: mongoose

I`m creating an application that is calculating average rating of a tour, that is based on user`s reviews. So when a user is updating or deleting his review avgRating should be recalculated. I used combination of pre- and post- middleware like this:

```
reviewSchema.pre(/^findOneAnd/, async function (next) {
  this.r = await this.findOne().clone();
  next();
});

reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, async function () {
  await this.r.constructor.calcAvgRatings(this.r.tour);
});
```

But for some reason pre middleware works good (based on console logs), but post middleware doesn`t triggered at all. What could be my problem?

Specify if any additional information needed.